# VST .wav Player

Tags: live, vst

I'm wondering if there are any VST plugins out there that are designed to play (not sample) a .wav file exactly how it was recorded without any changes at all. I'm using a live VST host, so you can't just dump the .wav in the DAW and play it, it has to be played directly from the host using a VST plugin. There are samplers like these (http://www.madtracker.org/plugins.php?category=instrument&subcategory=Sample+player) that work, but they seem really complex and are designed to distort the original sound instead of reproducing it faithfully. Also, they all require a MIDI keyboard to trigger the sound.

So are there any (free) VST plugins that do this task? Preferably, they can be controlled by the mouse without an external MIDI device.

Comment: This is quite trivial to write with something like SynthMaker. Actually I think I have done it sometime. I could send you the VST (not right now, though... SynthMaker isn't exactly GNU/Linux-friendly) if you don't find another one.

Comment: I've been looking around for several days and can't find anything that does not need a MIDI controller (I don't have one yet) and can be directly controlled with the mouse. If you have the VST, please send it to me.

Comment: So I got myself around to opening that project, and exported it as a VST .dll. But loading that in a DAW kind of just blew up the whole system... sorry. I suppose I could fix it, but I don't intend to spend much time on that, at least not now.

Comment: What is the usage of this: are you using an amp sim w/ASIO drivers and want a way to play MP3 files (etc) the same speakers you are using for the instrument?

Comment: @leftaroundabout... I tried making one using Synthedit and I failed miserably as well. However, I found another program (link attached) that does the job and I'm using it now. Thx for your help.

http://www.sawstudiouser.com/forums/showthread.php?t=15991

Comment: @the_stackX You ought to add that as an answer!

Comment: Migrate to SD please Tim......

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Rehearse VST plugin. This plugin supports wave playback triggered by midi events and mouse clicks. The plugin is free.

See: http://www.fatbee.nl

Answer (score 0):

here is the magical wav sound player VsWavPlayer not easy to find, but there it is now, you can add 3 or 4 in your daw as well, does the job, plays your original wav file without distorting it http://www.vstream.be/Vsti.html